# Class property includes instance of a template class (error C3857)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am implementing a binary tree class that is almost identical to [this one](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html). However, in my task, the `node` struct must be a templated structure. Therefore I changed `struct node` to:

```
template <typename T>
class node {
public:
    T data;
    node<T> *left, *right;
}
```

so far so good, until I added a `node` instance to `btree` as a member variable:

```
class btree {
    // ......
private:
    template <typename T>
    node<T> *root = NULL; // error
}
```

error message says

> C3857: multiple template parameter lists are not allowed.

I tried to move `root = NULL` to `btree`'s default constructor, does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a templated variable declaration.  There would be no way to specify the type to use for the variable.  You can either make `btree` a template and use that type for the `node`

```
template<typename T>
class btree {
    // ......
private:
    node<T> *root = NULL; // error
}
```

or specify what type of node you want in `btree`

```
class btree {
    // ......
private:
    node<some_type> *root = NULL; // error
}
```